# Gateway timeout issue and high CPU utilization issue

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, performance, amazon-rds, magento2

I am running my web application in Magento 2.4.3-p1

The daily customer visitor count is **5K**

The daily order count is **6k**

**Cron** running for place recurring orders on every **5** minutes

More than **200** admin users for daily activity in admin panel

Server architecture is **Single RDS** connected with **5 servers** instances

I am configuring a third-party shipping module also and it will interact with the Magento application via **rest API** to update shipping status and it will hit **400 hits per minute**.

**Nowadays I am facing continuously timeout issues and High CPU utilization issues**

Please suggest any useful ideas to improve performance on the Magento admin panel.

Also, suggest system and hardware requirements for instance and RDS

Comment: Change to bigger instance type.

Comment: @Marcin what is the minimum instance type for this large data?

Comment: The good thing about cloud that you can start small and keep increasing when needed. Go with next available size, observe metrics, and then keep increasing until you are satisfied.